# How to create MacOS/Linux link for reading data file?

Tags: r, linux, macos, ln

I have a huge raw data file which I do not intend to change or copy. And I have two projects in `RStudio` and both need to be able to access it.

I originally created the alias (in MacOS) in the following way
right click the file `~/A/data.csv` in finder, and click "make alias". Then copy the alias to `~/B/` and rename it `~/B/data.csv`

I also tried the following command later
`ln -s ~/A/data.csv ~/B`

For project A, I put the actual data file in A/data/data.csv.
For project B, I created an alias under B/data/.

But when I try fread('B/data/data.csv'), it complains:

> sh: ./data/data.csv: Too many levels of symbolic links
>
> Error in fread("./data/data.csv") :
>
> File is empty: /var/folders/4h/2jg64xk52mv3fyq4sb7s371w0000gn/T//Rtmp7cWNN3/filebf3013ad9194

I think I can use a hard link to solve this issue, but just want to see if I can use alias to make it work.

=====
I don't think it matters, but for completeness, see the following for my OS and R version:

```
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin10.8.0                
system         x86_64, darwin10.8.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.0                         
year           2014                        
month          04                          
day            10                          
svn rev        65387                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
nickname       Spring Dance
```

Comment: What is the entire error message?  Please add it to your post. Have you tried adding a `~` to the beginning of the file name i.e. `"~/B/data/data.csv"`

Comment: I added the entire error message now. I am trying to avoid using `~` since I want to use relative path (relative to the project). But, I did try using `~` following your suggestion. But it did not work.

Comment: Please show the command you used to create the symlink.

Comment: I tried two ways, 
1. right click the file `~/A/data.csv` in finder, and click "make alias". Then copy the alias to `~/B/` and rename it `~/B/data.csv`
2. `ln -s ~/A/data.csv ~/B`

Comment: Strictly this is a Linux/MacOS question, nothing specific to R. It's also probably a duplicate and should probably be closed-as-duplicate.

Comment: 'alias' is just MacOS UI jargon for 'soft link'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why using aliases in this specific case:

- note that for small files (e.g. < 1 MB), the alias can have a way bigger memory footprint. For example, for a simple text file containing "test" (`echo "test" > test.txt`) the alias will be 274k times bigger:

> test.txt: 5 bytes
>
> test.txt alias: 1372636 bytes

- since RStudio is good at using absolute paths, why not directly link to `~/A/data.csv` directly rather than linking to it's alias?

Two alternative solutions (not directly answering question) could be to (1) copy the file or (2) create a kind of symbolic link.

### Copying the file

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ~/B/data/
cp ~/A/data.csv ~/B/data/
```

Or in `R`, using `system` (on Mac):

```
system("mkdir ~/B/data/")
system("cp ~/A/data.csv ~/B/data/")
```

### Creating a symbolic link

This can be done by simply saving the path of the file `~/A/data.csv` in `~/B/data/`.

In shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ~/B/data/
echo "~/A/data.csv" > ~/B/data/data.csv
```

(this part can be also done in `R` using `system()` as above)
And then, in `R`:

```
## Reading path in B/data/
PATH <- scan(file = "~/B/data/data.csv", what = character())
## Opening the file (~/A/data/data.csv)
my_csv <- read.csv(PATH)
```